# PIGPIO undefined reference to clock_nanosleep

Tags: raspbian, pigpio

I have a Raspberry Pi with an up to date Raspbian installation and 
I am using code blocks tools to compile an example program from PIGPIO.
The compile fails with an:

> undefined reference to 'clock_nanosleep'

From what I have been able to learn from google searches it seems that `clock_nanosleep` is a function that requires `time.h` to be included.

What library or code is missing that contains `clock_nanosleep` and how do I go about explaining to Code::Blocks where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great Linux resource for C functions are the man pages.

If you execute `man clock_nanosleep` it will tell you which includes you need.  It will also tell you that you may need to include the real time library with `-lrt`.

You are probably missing `-lrt` in your build command.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much. You diagnosed the problem exactly, I was missing the -lrt